# Run string from command line with parameters and switches using powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have a powershell script that copies a file to a remote computer, and I need to execute it from a command line and with arguments/parameters.

Here is what I have...and I can't get it to work:

```
Get-Content C:/temp/list.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        $source = "\\server\folder\my application 1.2.1.EXE"
        $destination = "\\" + $_ + "\C$\temp\"
        New-Item -Path  $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
        Copy-Item -path $source -Destination $destination  -force | Out-Null
        & "$_ +"\C:\temp\my application 1.2.1.EXE" Location=07 /s" ##| Out-Null

        $status = "Success"
        }
    Catch {
        $status = "Failed"
        }
    "$_, $status" | out-file -filepath c:\temp\restult1.csv -Append -Encoding ascii
}
```

Comment: Use `robocopy` and tell it to create a log file.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help?  It copies great.  I don't know how to execute it from cmd.

Comment: What do you mean? Just type the command and press `Enter`.

Comment: From what I figure, I need to invoke cmd.exe on the remote computer, and run "C:\temp\my application 1.2.1.EXE" Location=07 /s"...I'm not sure the syntax on that.

Comment: I think you need to reword your question. Why do you need to copy a file to a remote computer? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.

```
Get-Content C:/temp/list.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        $source = "\\server\folder\my application 1.2.1.EXE"
        $destination = "\\" + $_ + "\C$\temp\"
        New-Item -Path  $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
        Copy-Item -path $source -Destination $destination  -force | Out-Null
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
        & cmd.exe /c "C:\temp\my application 1.2.1.EXE" Location=07 /s ##| Out-Null
        }
        $file = $destination + "my application 1.2.1.EXE"
        Remove-Item $file -Force
        $status = "Success"
        }
    Catch {
        $status = "Failed"
        }
    "$_, $status" | out-file -filepath c:\temp\restult1.csv -Append -Encoding ascii
}
```